# How to change background of custom notification bar button

Tags: android, notifications, imageview

How to change background image of notificationbar button,i want to play /pause on one button but i can't change background image.

```
public static void setListeners(RemoteViews view, Context context) {
    // Intent pause = new Intent(NOTIFY_PAUSE);
    Intent play = new Intent(context, NotificationBroadcast.class);

    PendingIntent pPlay = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, play,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    view.setImageViewResource(R.id.buttonplay, R.drawable.play_button);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonplay, pPlay);

}
```

Comment: Please once check this thread, I guess your question is duplicate of "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436977/play-pause-button-image-in-notification-android" , they have successfuly achieved the same.

Comment: but i cant control my issue how  can I solve,your code is not work in my example